# how to config proxy.config.json for angular

Tags: angular, http, proxy, config

I use a proxy.config.json for the http-calls.

my example:

```
 "/api/countries/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8084/countries",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api/countries": ""
    },
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

I have to call http://localhost:8084/countries. (works fine) and
http://localhost:8084/countries/textParam

The latter is not proxied. it is rewritten to just: /textParam

[HPM] Rewriting path from "/api/countries/textParam" to "/textParam"

And the http.put-request looses the textParam.

[HPM] PUT /api/countries/textParam ~> http://localhost:8084/countries

I could not find a doc that helped me.

how do I have to enhance my config?

thanx for helping.

Comment: try `"target":"http://localhost:8084",`

Comment: sorry, doesn't work. in this case I don't get the request for countries and therefore error,

Comment: did you try deleting the  "pathRewrite" part ? check this article https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Comment: sorry, didn't help for my put-rewuest with id at the end of url. haven't found an explanation yet, that helped.

Comment: I found it. proxy-config was OK. I had another, deeper error, which I now found. learned a lot again. thank you for consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try ,
"target":"http://localhost:8084"

and try /api/* instead of /api/countries/* .

please refer this link https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

Comment: The link is broken.